# How to set second in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, time, type-conversion

I import data from CSV using Python. I want to calculate the mean for every row and column using time-variable only. But the problem is the value is not in seconds.

How can I declare the related variable into time which is **second** instead of numeric value?

this is my data

```
--------------------------
|Responses|Time 1 | Time 2 | Time 3| 
| abc     |20     |   30   |  40   |
| bce     |23     |   25   |  30   |  
| cde     |34     |   40   |  20   |
```

So, I want to calculate the sum time for each response

```
df.sum(axis = 1)
abc  90    
bce  78
cde  92

df.sum(axis = 0)
Time 1    76
Time 2    95
Time 3    90
```

But actually I want it in minutes second which is

```
df.sum(axis = 0)
Time 1    1:16
Time 2    1:35
Time 3    1:30
```

Or it can be 1 minute 16 seconds or something. Anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Hi @farahamiramh, Did my below answer answered your question? Or is there anything else that is not clear? I was just wondering why this ticket is still open :-)

Comment: Hi @RomainCapron . you did answer my question. But I am wondering if there is any simple way that I can do. But it is okay. And sorry, I did not know how to close this ticket.

Comment: Hi @farahamiramh, if your question was answered, please vote on, and accept the most helpful answer. You can do that by clicking the grey check next to the answer to toggle it green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not really well defined. You should follow the instructions, as suggested in the comments by jezrael.

As you said "Or it can be 1 minute 16 seconds or something.", I assumed that the output can simply be a string.

If you want the result as:

- 1:16, use to_minutes_seconds(x)
- 1 minute 16 seconds, use to_minutes_seconds_text(x)

```
from datetime import timedelta

def to_minutes_seconds(x):
    # x is the current value to process, for example 76
    td = timedelta(seconds=x)

    # split x into 3 variables: hours, minutes and seconds
    hours, remainder = divmod(td.seconds, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)

    # return the required format, minutes:seconds
    return "{}:{}".format(minutes, seconds)


def to_minutes_seconds_text(x):
    td = timedelta(seconds=x)
    hours, remainder = divmod(td.seconds, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)

    if minutes > 1:
        m = 'minutes'
    else:
        m = 'minute'

    if seconds > 1:
        s = 'seconds'
    else:
        s = 'second'

    return "{} {} {} {}".format(minutes, m, seconds, s)


# Create the input dictionary
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Responses': [76, 95, 90, 781]})

# Change the total seconds into the required format
df['Time'] = df['Responses'].apply(to_minutes_seconds)
df['Text'] = df['Responses'].apply(to_minutes_seconds_text)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Responses  Time                 Text
0         76  1:16  1 minute 16 seconds
1         95  1:35  1 minute 35 seconds
2         90  1:30  1 minute 30 seconds
3        781  13:1  13 minutes 1 second
```